# Screenshots of Blueprint view with Layout Editor?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout-editor

When in the [Layout Editor](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html) of Android Studio 2.3.3 or 3.0, I can take screenshots of the Design view, but neither of the Blueprint view nor of both views together.

This behavior is independent from my selection of the `Show Design`, `Show Blueprint`, `Show Design + Blueprint` buttons. When `Show Blueprint` is selected and I take a screenshot by `right click` on the *Blueprint* view and `Save Screenshot`, I will still get a screenshot of the *Design* view.

Since on SO single screenshots with both views are abounding, I am led to believe that this is a function inherent to Android Studio. How can I, too, take screenshots of both views simultaneously, relying solely on tools built into Android Studio?